# .htaccess issue with Codeigniter under Sub folder of React application

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to deploy one react application with its API(Codeigniter 3 Rest API) to cPanel.

Folder structure:

[image]

The .htaccess file for main folder is:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>


  #######################################################################
  # GENERAL                                                             #
  #######################################################################

  # Make apache follow sym links to files
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  # If somebody opens a folder, hide all files from the resulting folder list
  IndexIgnore */*


  #######################################################################
  # REWRITING                                                           #
  #######################################################################

  # Enable rewriting
  RewriteEngine On

  # If its not HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

  # Comment out the RewriteCond above, and uncomment the RewriteCond below if you're using a load balancer (e.g. CloudFlare) for SSL
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

  # Redirect to the same URL with https://, ignoring all further rules if this one is in effect
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

  # If we get to here, it means we are on https://

  # If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # and the directory with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # and we are not opening the root already (otherwise we get a redirect loop)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$

  # Rewrite all requests to the root
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /

</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Do not cache sw.js, required for offline-first updates.
  <FilesMatch "sw\.js$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

And the .htaccess for subfolder i.e. Codeigniter application is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://react-demo.mydomain.in/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

#Redirect for CORS Preflight request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
#Set headers to access CORS Requests / allowing localhost only
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

But when i am trying to access the API it gives 404 error.

Codeigniter API Url stucture: https://react-demo.mydomain.in/api/v1/website

Localhost Url stucture: http://localhost:3787/v1/website/1

Can anyone please help with this. What could be the issue.

Comment: What type of 404 are you getting? The 404 returned by CodeIgniter? Or the 404 returned by Apache? Your .htaccess file works as it should in the sandbox I setup. I suspect it's a controller / route issue.

Comment: @MarshallC
It is the 404 returned by Apache. I tried removing v1 and setting set the Default controller in config, e.g. https://react-demo.mydomain.in/api, then I can access the Url, but only for GET request. If i use https://react-demo.mydomain.in/api/website then again it reutns 404 for all the verbs.

Comment: @MarshallC
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: So you're able to get the CodeIgniter welcome page at example.com/api but you get the apache error page on example.com/api/website ?

Comment: @MarshallC Yes exactly. I am able to run in local wih IIS too. But on server its apache and it giving me a trouble.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you don't have overrides allowed in your apache site config. `AllowOverride All`. But I'm not even sure that's what the problem is. Sorry I can't help more.